# Finding limit when limit approches to infinity

Tags: limits

> Finding $\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\bigg[\frac{y}{e}-y\bigg(\frac{y}{y+1}\bigg)^y\bigg]$

**Attempt:** Put $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{z}$ . Then $\displaystyle \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\bigg[\frac{1}{ze}-\frac{1}{z}\bigg(\frac{z}{z+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{z}}\bigg]$

Could some help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: That should be $\lim_{z\to 0}$.

Comment: Is the answer $\frac {-1}{2e} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$\log\left[\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)^y\right]
=-y\log\left(1+\frac1y\right)=-1+\frac1{2y}+O(y^{-2}).$$
Therefore
$$\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)^y=e^{-1}\exp\left(\frac1{2y}+O(y^{-2})
\right)=e^{-1}\left(1+\frac1{2y}+O(y^{-2})\right)$$
etc.

Comment: It would add to the readability of your answer if you mention that in the last step you are using Taylor's expansion...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\left(\frac{y}{y+1}\right)^y=\left(1-\frac1{y+1}\right)^{y+1-1}\longrightarrow\frac1e.$$

**Update:** Since the hint might be too difficult for some users: $$\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{-1}{y+1}\right)^{y+1}\cdot\underbrace{\left(1-\frac{1}{y+1}\right)^{-1}}_{\rightarrow 1}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{-1}{y}\right)^y=e^{-1}=\frac1e.$$

Comment: That won't suffice here.

Comment: @MarkViola: Do tell, because that is precisely how it can be solved without resorting to Taylor expansions...

Comment: OK.  I'll tell.  You lucked out.  You need to expand to second order to rigorously conclude.